# Gumbel-Softmax Activation in a generative adversarial network in Tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, binary, sequence, softmax

My goal is to build a generative adversarial network which generates real looking sequences of a categorical variable, similar to [1]. In order to generate categorical sequences with the generator I need to use the Gumbel_Softmax activation to make sure the backpropagation still works. I can't find a preformulated Gumbel_softmax activation function in Tensorflow 2.1 just the tfp.distributions.RelaxedOneHotCategorical which should work for my problem.

In my example I would like to generate a sequence of binary varaibles.
Can you give me a code example of how to implement this in tensorflow functional API.

Maybe you can grasp my objective from my current code:

```
generator():

    inputs = Input(latent_dim,)

    x = Dense(t_steps* no_states, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Reshape((t_steps, no_states))(x)

    x = tfpl.RelaxedOneHotCategorical(temperature=t, logits=no_states, Batch_shape=t_steps)

    outputs=x

    noise = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    inp = model(noise)

    return Model(noise, inp)
```

[1] GANS for Sequences of Discrete Elements with the Gumbel-softmax Distribution by Kusner et al. 2016

Answer (score 2):

I have built a custom GumbelSoftmax layer for usage in Tensorflow 2+.

When using with GANs, it is said that is better to use the inverse temperature parameter, i.e., multiplying `y * tau` instead of `y / tau`.

https://github.com/gugarosa/nalp/blob/master/nalp/models/layers/gumbel_softmax.py